# How select a "choice type" value automaticaly?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have created in infopath a sharepoint form that is from a list. A field is set to a choice type.

What I would want is if selected than set to choice 1 if the item is new and choice 2 if the item is modified.

Help please

Answer (score 1):

Consider looking at the CurrentItem's ID. If it exists, you know it is an existing form, if not, it is a new form. Then add the logic to select correct item based on that.